# how to break file upload operation if file extension does not matching with my criteria? 

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I have written one jquery code of upload files with Web Handler. It works fine but i want to check if file's extension is not matching with my criteria than it will not allow to upload the file..

Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function () {

            var button = $('#fuAttachment'), interval;
            $.ajax_upload(button, {
                action: 'FileUploader.ashx',
                name: 'myfile',
                onSubmit: function (file, ext) {
                    if (ext == "js") {
                        alert(ext);
                    }
                    //  this.disable();
                },
                onComplete: function (file, response) {
                    window.clearInterval(interval);
                    $('<li></li>').appendTo('.files').text(file);
                }
            });
            });
```

I am getting the extension in `ext` variable.
I can check it also but still if file contain that extension than want to break upload operation.
How can i do this?? please help ME if anybody knows..

Comment: What's `$.ajax_upload`? Where does it come from? Custom written (if so, please show the code)? Third party upload plugin (if so please post a link to the website of the plugin)?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: It comes from jquery library  `jquery.ajax_upload.0.6.min.js`. You can get it from this [link](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-plugins-collections/downloads/detail?name=jquery.ajax_upload.0.6.js&can=2&q=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could return `false` from the `onSubmit` function to prevent the file upload if some condition is not satisfied:

```
onSubmit: function (file, ext) {
    if (ext == "js") {
        // the extension of the selected file was .js => allow upload
        return true;
    }

    // the extension is not .js => don't do the upload
    return false;
}
```